# What's the possibility to slow down the web application after migrated to azure cloud service?

Tags: performance, azure, migration

We have migrated the existing web application to azure cloud service, using azure database and azure redis cache provider.

We visit the same page in azure platform and local machine

1. In azure platform it takes 2 seconds to execute this page.
2. In local machine,it only takes 500 ms.
3. Both environment are using the same azure database and the same azure redis.
4. The location of azure database ,azure redis ,cloud service are all in west europe.
5. We use large cloud service (4 cores, 8GB memroy)
6. We also execute the page in cloud service machine by using remote desktop, try to prove that it's not due to the network, and it's still very slow.

Does anybody has experience about this, why it's so slow to execute the same page in azure (by using the same database and the same cache provider)?

Comment: I would recommend putting some tracing into your code to identify the source of the slowdown. When you say the local run takes the time that it does is that including a complete tear down and rebuild of the app locally (i.e. ensuring nothing is cached)?  I would also check that the web.config that is being deployed to your cloud service has all the same configuration elements as that running locally.

Comment: i copy the code from azure cloud server to my local, and it's very fast